# could not extract ResultSet in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a problem with *Hibernate*. I try to parse to List but It throws an exception: `HTTP Status 500 - could not extract ResultSet`. When I debug, It fault at line `query.list()`...

My sample code here

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="ID_CATALOG")
@GeneratedValue 
private Integer idCatalog;

@Column(name="Catalog_Name")
private String catalogName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="catalog", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);

//getter & setter & constructor
//...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="id_product")
@GeneratedValue 
private Integer idProduct;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CATALOG")
private Catalog catalog;

@Column(name="product_name")
private String productName;

@Column(name="date")
private Date date;

@Column(name="author")
private String author;

@Column(name="price")
private Integer price;

@Column(name="linkimage")
private String linkimage;

//getter & setter & constructor
}



@Repository
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO {
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public List<Product> searchProductByCatalog(String catalogid, String keyword) {
    String sql = "select p from Product p where 1 = 1";
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    if (keyword.trim().equals("") == false) {
        sql += " and p.productName like '%" + keyword + "%'";
    }
    if (catalogid.trim().equals("-1") == false
            && catalogid.trim().equals("") == false) {
        sql += " and p.catalog.idCatalog = " + Integer.parseInt(catalogid);
    }
    Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
    List listProduct = query.list();
    return listProduct;
}

}
```

My beans

```xml
  <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.shopmvc"/>

  <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with 
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shoesshopdb?autoReconnect=true"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="12345"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.shopmvc.pojo</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:948)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause 

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:61)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2036)

root cause 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product0_.ID_CATALOG' in 'field list'
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2036)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1815)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2522)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2508)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2338)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2333)
    org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
```

My Database:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `catalog` (
  `ID_CATALOG` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Catalog_Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_CATALOG`)
)

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id_product` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `author` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `linkimage` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`),
  KEY `FK_Product_idx` (`catalog_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Product` FOREIGN KEY (`catalog_id`) REFERENCES `catalog` (`ID_CATALOG`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `@JoinColumn` annotation specifies the name of the column being used as the foreign key on the targeted entity.

On the `Product` class above, the name of the join column is set to `ID_CATALOG`.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ID_CATALOG")
private Catalog catalog;
```

However, the foreign key on the `Product` table is called `catalog_id`

```
`catalog_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

You'll need to change either the column name on the table or the name you're using in the `@JoinColumn` so that they match. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-association

Answer (score 35):

Another potential cause, for other people coming across the same error message is that this error will occur if you are accessing a table in a different schema from the one you have authenticated with.

In this case you would need to add the schema name to your entity entry:

```
@Table(name= "catalog", schema = "targetSchemaName")
```

Comment: it occurred in my case when i tried creating new sboot -mysql -jpa app. no db table was created. this solved my issue.

Comment: or when the table name doesn't match... like `@Table(name = "catalog", schema = "taretSchemaName")` and the table name is `taretSchemaName`.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue, when I tried to update a row:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE data SET value = 'asdf'", nativeQuery = true)
void setValue();
```

My Problem was that I forgot to add the `@Modifying` annotation:

```
@Modifying    
@Query(value = "UPDATE data SET value = 'asdf'", nativeQuery = true)
void setValue();
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have 'HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE' sequence created in database (if use oracle or any sequence based database), you shall get same type of error;

Ensure the sequence is present there;

Comment: could you elaborate?

Comment: If you are using oracle DB and have disabled the auto schema creation you are probably missing the sequence `HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE` too. If this is your case you can try changing the generated value annotation to something else, like: `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` if you are ofc using the identity generation on your column `id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,`

Answer (score 8):

I Used the following properties in my application.properties file and the issue got resolved

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

and

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

earlier was getting an error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:254)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
```

Comment: I guess this is the (sometimes better) alternative to explicitely annotating with @Table(name= "catalog", schema = "targetSchemaName") as suggested above. Better, because when you copy code from an EE application, then you don't have to  modify the entity classes.

Answer (score 7):

Try using inner join in your Query

```
    Query query=session.createQuery("from Product as p INNER JOIN p.catalog as c 
    WHERE c.idCatalog= :id and p.productName like :XXX");
    query.setParameter("id", 7);
    query.setParameter("xxx", "%"+abc+"%");
    List list = query.list();
```

also in the hibernate config file have

```xml
<!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

To display what is being queried on the console.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue. Try use the HQL editor. It will display you the SQL (as you have a SQL grammar exception). Copy your SQL and execute it separately. In my case the problem was in schema definition. I defined the schema, but I should leave it empty. This raised the same exception as you got. And the error description reflected the actual state, as the schema name was included in SQL statement.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem after migrating a database from online server to localhost. The schema changed so I had to define the schema manually for each table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ESBCORE_DOMAIN", schema = "SYS")
```

Answer (score 3):

For **MySql** take in mind that it's not a good idea to write *camelcase*.
For example if the schema is like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `teaching_hours` DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `isActive` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
    `is_validated` BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You must be very careful cause `isActive` column will translate to `isactive`.
So in your Entity class is should be like this:

```
 @Basic
 @Column(name = "isactive", nullable = true)
 public boolean isActive() {
     return isActive;
 }
 public void setActive(boolean active) {
     isActive = active;
 }
```

That was my problem at least that got me your error

This has nothing to do with **MySql** which is case insensitive, but rather is a naming strategy that spring will use to translate your tables.
For more refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353492/jpa-uppercase-table-names/36398277)

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was first uppercase/lowercase differences between my local workspace and dev database server's table name.

Example:

```
select name from customer;
```

vs

```
select name from Customer;
```

By fixing the typo the error was gone.

Hope this will be a solution for someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Spring Data JPA with PostgreSql and during UPDATE call it was showing errors-

- '**could not extract ResultSet**' and another one.
- org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing
  an update/delete query; nested exception is
  javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
  update/delete query. (*Showing Transactional required.*)

Actually, I was **missing** two required Annotations.

- @Transactional and
- @Modifying

*With-*

```
@Query(vlaue = " UPDATE DB.TABLE SET Col1 = ?1 WHERE id = ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
void updateCol1(String value, long id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is add @JsonIgnore :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="catalog", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Product> products = new HashSet<Product>(0);
```

Comment: Explain how this would solve the the problem buddy. The answer-seeker would benefit more by understanding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This message also appears if you by mistake use a reserved keyword for your table (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-C). When doing a join on a table which has the name the sama as the reserved mysql keyword you would get the same message, although everything else is correct.
Hopefully this will spare some time and pain for other people.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced similar issue:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:279)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)

...

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'setting0_.advance_payment_first_text' in 'field list'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:975)
```

And in my specific use case it was because of the conflict between new dump which was used for database and `liquibase` configuration files `data.xml` with logic like:

```
<changeSet  author="liquibase-docs"  id="sqlFile-data">
        <sqlFile  dbms="!h2, oracle, mysql"
                  encoding="UTF-8"
                  path="..\..\..\sql\data.sql"
                  relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                  splitStatements="true"
                  stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

and `structure.xml`:

```
<changeSet  author="liquibase-docs"  id="sqlFile-structure">
        <sqlFile  dbms="!h2, oracle, mysql"
                  encoding="UTF-8"
                  path="..\..\..\sql\structure.sql"
                  relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                  splitStatements="true"
                  stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

for old scripts of the project.

After some investigations by checking the correspondence of tables with columns in the code I understood these old scripts overwrote after running the project new dump.

So after removing old scripts `data.sql` and `structure.sql` with configuration files `data.xml` and `structure.xml` from the project this problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I had changed the ddl property to create-drop, and I ran it after the tables were deleted.

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop**

just put the ddl to create, and after that, return to none (not to change the database anymore)

**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none**

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, because I had a field mapped in the Entity that did not exist in the database